# How do I count unique page view count to my web page using Cakephp 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.2, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.3

I'm trying to implement total unique page view count to my webpage, Any one knows that how to do that just give me an idea to implement using CakePHP 3.0

Comment: ip based filter

Comment: When a user comes to your website chceck if he has your cookie if not store it. Count it and if the cookie was found ignore it

Comment: You can use IP, $this->request->clientIp()  this is the method to get client IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create table for page view

ex:

```
CREATE TABLE `pageview` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `page` text NOT NULL,
 `userip` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

then store visitor ip address into your table using

```
// gets the user IP Address
  $userip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is best method to get count unique page view count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking both COOKIE and IP
There is a Plugins written by CakeManager which give those facility with proper functionality

https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-analyzer